# Rails own config/initializers updated and doesn't display changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I work on a web app that was already coded, and I have to bring some new features to improve it. I have to add 2 field in the rails admin, and there are some file type that I have never work with like .yml files.

I have a file called : `simple_form.fr.yml`, that permit to use on the view : `human_attribute_name` on a class. but I made a modification on a line (change "hello" to "hello world" for example) and I can't see the modification on the view ...

Should I did a command line to make modifications available ?

Thank ! (don't hesitate to ask if you need more precisions / code, I'll update my question)

**EDIT**

The yml document :

```
fr:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      school:
        code_online_access: "Accès code en ligne"
```

the line that I change is code_online_access, I juste change the content of the string and in the view I have this line :

```
<%= School.human_attribute_name("code_online_access") %>
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after modification?

Comment: Yes I did, I work on localhost:3000 for the moment

Comment: You need to restart server for all the time for every changes you done in rails admin

Comment: Well, hard to say what's wrong there, without seeing enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev just editing my question for more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing a label for simple_form, but expect the change to show up in `human_attribute_name`. This method does not look in simple_form's section.

Take a look at [this section of I18n rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) to learn correct place to put your translations to.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Dude
    attributes:
      user:
        login: "Handle"
      # will translate User attribute "login" as "Handle"
```

then

```
User.human_attribute_name("login") # => 'Handle'
```